# Merge duplicate items in array of objects, concating nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that contains duplicates.
I need to remove the duplicate while keeping the nested items objects.

To make it clear, this is what my source array looks like:

```
const src = [
  {
    id: '5f10b85e145d7163d818066e',
    name: 'Product 1',
    vendor: 'Vendor 1',
    instances: [
      {
        id: '5f10b8f6145d7163d8180672',
        operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2016',
        environment: 'Prod',
        version: '4.0',
        notes: '',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '5f10b856145d7163d818066d',
    name: 'Product 1',
    vendor: 'Vendor 2',
    instances: [
      {
        id: '5f10b8c5145d7163d8180671',
        operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2012R2',
        environment: 'Prod',
        version: '4.1',
        notes: '',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '5f10b85e145d7163d818066e',
    name: 'Product 1',
    vendor: 'Vendor 1',
    instances: [
      {
        id: '5f10b8f6145d7163d8180672',
        operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2016',
        environment: 'Prod',
        version: '4.0',
        notes: '',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

`Product 1` of `Vendor 1` (with the same `id`) is duplicated.
I need the instances of the duplicates, to be merged with the first item.

The result array should look like this:

```
const target = [
  {
    id: '5f10b85e145d7163d818066e',
    name: 'Product 1',
    vendor: 'Vendor 1',
    instances: [
      {
        id: '5f10b8f6145d7163d8180672',
        operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2016',
        environment: 'Prod',
        version: '4.0',
        notes: '',
      },
      {
        id: '5f10b8f6145d7163d8180672',
        operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2016',
        environment: 'Prod',
        version: '4.0',
        notes: '',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '5f10b856145d7163d818066d',
    name: 'Product 1',
    vendor: 'Vendor 2',
    instances: [
      {
        id: '5f10b8c5145d7163d8180671',
        operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2012R2',
        environment: 'Prod',
        version: '4.1',
        notes: '',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce` and then wrap the response with `Object.values` to remove the keys added by reduce

```js
const src = [ { id: '5f10b85e145d7163d818066e', name: 'Product 1', vendor: 'Vendor 1', instances: [ { id: '5f10b8f6145d7163d8180672', operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2016', environment: 'Prod', version: '4.0', notes: '', }, ], }, { id: '5f10b856145d7163d818066d', name: 'Product 1', vendor: 'Vendor 2', instances: [ { id: '5f10b8c5145d7163d8180671', operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2012R2', environment: 'Prod', version: '4.1', notes: '', }, ], }, { id: '5f10b85e145d7163d818066e', name: 'Product 1', vendor: 'Vendor 1', instances: [ { id: '5f10b8f6145d7163d8180672', operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2016', environment: 'Prod', version: '4.0', notes: '', }, ], }, ];
var res=src.reduce((a,c)=>{
  if (!a[c.id]) a[c.id]= {...a[c.id],...c}
  else {
    a[c.id].instances.push(c.instances)
    a[c.id].instances=[].concat(...a[c.id].instances);
  }
return a
},{})
console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: `Map` based solutions (e.g. [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985667/11299053)) will work [muuuch faster](https://jsbench.me/q0kctm5daa/1)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov do you have any resources or something to prove that ?

Comment: Would you bother to follow the link in the first comment?

Comment: would you bother provide a resource because the link you provided doesn't prove anything

Comment: If you don't trust my benchmark you may do yours. Proving anything to the person refusing to believe one's own eyes see, doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to keep the ids and the first occurrence of an object.

Then using the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function check if an id has already been added.

```js
const src = [
    { id: 'foo', name: 'Product 1', instances: [{ key: 'value a' }] },
    { id: 'bar', name: 'Product 2', instances: [{ key: 'value b' }] },
    { id: 'foo', name: 'Product 1', instances: [{ key: 'value c' }] }
];

const unique = new Map();

const target = src.filter((product) => {
    if (unique.has(product.id)) {
        unique.get(product.id).instances.push(...product.instances);
        return false;
    }

    unique.set(product.id, product);
    return true;
});

console.log(target);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to traverse source array and build up the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where `id` is used as a key, so once you get duplicating `id`, you push instances of the current object into existing entry, or set new entry, otherwise. When `Map` is ready, you simply extract its values with [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values):

```js
const src = [{id:'5f10b85e145d7163d818066e',name:'Product 1',vendor:'Vendor 1',instances:[{id:'5f10b8f6145d7163d8180672',operatingSystem:'Microsoft Windows 2016',environment:'Prod',version:'4.0',notes:'',},],},{id:'5f10b856145d7163d818066d',name:'Product 1',vendor:'Vendor 2',instances:[{id:'5f10b8c5145d7163d8180671',operatingSystem:'Microsoft Windows 2012R2',environment:'Prod',version:'4.1',notes:'',},],},{id:'5f10b85e145d7163d818066e',name:'Product 1',vendor:'Vendor 1',instances:[{id:'5f10b8f6145d7163d8180672',operatingSystem:'Microsoft Windows 2016',environment:'Prod',version:'4.0',notes:'',},],},],

      result = [...src
        .reduce((r, o) => {
          const dupe = r.get(o.id)
          dupe ? 
          dupe.instances.push(...o.instances) : 
          r.set(o.id, o)
          return r
        }, new Map())
        .values()
      ]
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways to go about it. Here's one.

```js
const src = [{
    id: '5f10b85e145d7163d818066e',
    name: 'Product 1',
    vendor: 'Vendor 1',
    instances: [{
      id: '5f10b8f6145d7163d8180672',
      operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2016',
      environment: 'Prod',
      version: '4.0',
      notes: '',
    }, ],
  },
  {
    id: '5f10b856145d7163d818066d',
    name: 'Product 1',
    vendor: 'Vendor 2',
    instances: [{
      id: '5f10b8c5145d7163d8180671',
      operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2012R2',
      environment: 'Prod',
      version: '4.1',
      notes: '',
    }, ],
  },
  {
    id: '5f10b85e145d7163d818066e',
    name: 'Product 1',
    vendor: 'Vendor 1',
    instances: [{
      id: '5f10b8f6145d7163d8180672',
      operatingSystem: 'Microsoft Windows 2016',
      environment: 'Prod',
      version: '4.0',
      notes: '',
    }, ],
  },
];

function deDupe(input) {
  let result = [];
  let productMap = {};
  input.forEach((product, idx) => {
    if (!productMap[product.id]) {
      productMap[product.id] = input[idx];
    } else {
      productMap[product.id].instances.push(...input[idx].instances);
    }
  });

  return Object.values(productMap)
}

console.log(deDupe(src));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a map from `id` to objects like:

```
const map = {}
...
// Given object:
if (object.id in map) {
  const object_master = map[object.id]
  object_master.instances.push(...object.instances)
} else map[object.id] = object
```